# Getting error while compiling akka actor source code using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, java-9, akka-actor

I want the source code of akka-actor v 2.4.17 and compile on my windows machine.

I downloaded the source code from below location.
https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/v2.4.17

After downloading the entire source code installed sbt on my machine, And ran sbt command on the command line in the project root directory.

While running I got the below error, Please let me know how to compile this source code.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1147)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1264)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1335)
        at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:797)
        at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:912)
        at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:6
6)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzing
Compiler.scala:188)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAn
alyzingCompiler.scala:166)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.sca
la:176)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:152)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala
:860)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:8
51)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:8
49)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
8)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
8)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executo
rs.java:514)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo
lExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Java 9. I had some issues using sbt with Java 9 in the past. I'm not sure if all problems have been fixed in a recent sbt version, but switching to Java 8 would most likely let you compile Akka successfully.

Comment: I have another query, I want to just build akka-actor which is a sub-project. when I run sbt compile I get the error --> error: not found: value AkkaBuild
AkkaBuild.defaultSettings  .Can you suggest please

Comment: Are you running sbt from the root folder, or the actor sub folder? You should always run sbt from the project root. If you want to build only a sub project in sbt, you can do that by running `sbt $sub-project/compile` e.g. `sbt akka-actor/compile`